# Apple rejection due to subscription in-app purchase bugs on iOS 13.3.1

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, review

The app works fine a long time and didn't get rejections related to IAP purchases. But last week I can't release application with bug fix of other part. I tried to send to review several times but got rejection again.
Attached screenshots from review team contains alert with message **Cannot connect to iTunes Store**

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs
>   when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 13.3.1 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Specifically, we got prompted the attached error message when we
>   attempted to buy a subscription.
>
> Next Steps
>
> When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able
>   to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s
>   test environment. The recommended approach is for your production
>   server to always validate receipts against the production App Store
>   first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used
>   in production," you should validate against the test environment
>   instead.
>
> Resources
>
> You can learn more about testing in-app purchase products in your
>   development sandbox environment in App Store Connect Developer Help.
>
> For more information on receipt validation, please see What url should
>   I use to verify my receipt? in the In-App Purchase FAQ.
>
> Learn how to generate a receipt validation code in App Store Connect
>   Developer Help.

I tried to catch this case, but only one times got alert **Cannot connect to iTunes Store** after subscription purchase. Unfortunately I can't reproduce it neither in debug mode or with build from TestFlight.
It seems that IAP works fine with sandbox user, but have issue with AppStore user(reproduced here).

**Maybe it's important:** I load receipt from AppStore before first purchase to check for active subscription.

Comment: Have you tried changing your server code to what they mention about always validate receipts against the production App Store first?

Comment: Yes, I'm triying to validate with production and then with sandbox environment in case of getting status 21007.

Comment: Are you doing this with your server webhooks?

Comment: @VikasRajput I don't use server, so validation works by requests from client

Comment: This is probably the reason why Apple rejected your app, because you're not allowed to call the App Store server /verifyReceipt endpoint from your app. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: @PaulSchröder Thank you! It seems that review process was changed or this new requirement added recently.
I will try to remove this validation and post the results.

Comment: @Arkadiy Hi! Did you manage to resolve that problem? Did moving the validation from the client to server works? Thx!